# eclipse debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Is there a way once you deploy an application via eclipse to tomcat to see the application step through in one of the console views as you navigate through the program on your browser??

I guess watch it as it accesses certain methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can put breakpoints in the code and step through as you navigate through the browser, but it won't behave exactly as you are imagining.  It'll be a back and forth dance:

1. Set a breakpoint on the server
2. Use the browser UI to access the code
3. Hit the breakpoint on the server
4. Check the status of variables
5. Set the next breakpoint
6. Tell the server code to continue
7. Go back to 2 and repeat